# Why can't I retrieve Refresh Token using the expo-auth-session/providers/google?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, refresh-token

I am unable to obtain refresh token from the response of useAuthRequest. (I am using expo for my react native app). Upon pressing a login button a promptAsync({useProxy:true, showInRecents: true}) is being executed, then on the response the useEffect provided must execute, printing to the console:

`{"accessToken": "a valid token", "expiresIn": "3599", "idToken": undefined, "issuedAt": 1677359716, "refreshToken": undefined, "scope": "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "state": "y2dMoLm6va", "tokenType": "Bearer"}`

Thanks!

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(
        {
            iosClientId: keys.iosClientId,
            androidClientId: keys.androidClientId,
            expoClientId: keys.expoClientId,
            accessType: 'offline'
        },
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useeffect 1');
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            setAuth(response.authentication);
            console.log(response.authentication.refresh_token); //WHY IS IT UNDEFINED????
            const persistAuth = async () => {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                    'auth',
                    JSON.stringify(response.authentication)
                );
            };

            persistAuth();
            getUserData(response.authentication);
        }
    }, [response]);
```

I have tried everything (any combination of parameters to pass to Google.useAuthRequest() that I could think of). What am I missing?

Comment: What scopes are you asking for?

Comment: Hey, @ToreNestenius, I have just found the solution to the problem and have posted it here. Took me some time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

So I just found the correct combination of parameters to pass in order to receive the refresh token. Here is the correct body to pass to useAuthRequest

```
{
        iosClientId: keys.iosClientId,
        androidClientId: keys.androidClientId,
        expoClientId: keys.expoClientId,
        clientSecret: 'your-client-secret-found-at-credentials',
        responseType: "code",
        prompt: 'consent',
        extraParams: {
            access_type: "offline"
          },
    },
    {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
        tokenEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'
    },
```

Comment: you just pasted this object to the useAuthRequest hook?

Comment: Yes, after a lot of trial and error, this combination gave me the results I needed. Anyways, that was some time ago and as far as I know there are a lot of changes with Expo, that is why I have paused for a bit, waiting for more in-depth documentation.

Comment: okay I see, If you run the app with expo go by providing the least required(iosClientId,androidClientId,expoClientID) you will get the refreshToken as underfined, however if you run it as a satndalone app or build the apk, you will get the refresh Token.